Is there anyway to access the configurable values
    public class HumanAgentSocket extends TextWebSocketHandler {
      
        @Value("${human.agents.available}")
        private int availableHumanAgents;
        private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> sessionIds = new ArrayList<>();
        private HashMap<WebSocketSession,WebSocketSession> socketConnections = new          HashMap<WebSocketSession,WebSocketSession>();
        private int noOfHumanAgents = 1;
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws IOException {
           if (noOfHumanAgents<=5){
               System.out.println("Agents "+availableHumanAgents);
               sessions.add(session);
            sessionIds.add(session.getId());
            System.out.println("List "+sessionIds);
            if(sessions.size() == 2){
                socketConnections.put(sessions.get(0),sessions.get(1));
                socketConnections.put(sessions.get(1),sessions.get(0));
                System.out.println("SocketConnections "+socketConnections);
                sessions.clear();
                noOfHumanAgents++;
                System.out.println("Sessios "+sessions.size());
            }
        }else {
            throw  new HumanAgentException("agents are busy");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        WebSocketSession webSocketSession = socketConnections.get(session);
        String payload = message.getPayload();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(payload);
        String content = jsonNode.get("message").asText();
        if (content.equalsIgnoreCase("CLOSE")){
            afterConnectionClosed(session,null);
        }
        if (webSocketSession.isOpen()){
            webSocketSession.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        WebSocketSession humanAgentSession = socketConnections.get(session);
        if(humanAgentSession!=null){
            sessions.add(humanAgentSession);
        }
        socketConnections.remove(session);
        socketConnections.remove(humanAgentSession);
    }

    public String getWebSocketSession(String sessionId){
        System.out.println("List "+sessionIds);
        String webSocketSession = sessionIds.get(Integer.parseInt(sessionId));
        return webSocketSession;
    }
}

Here I am trying to access the configurable value from application.properties and Even I tried from environment variables also but always it's value coming as 0 for 'availableHumanAgents' variable but the excepted will be the value which I specified or configured in application.properties file.

How is the HumanAgentSocket being created. Feels like it is non spring managed and thus @Value doesn't work.

@Component
public class HumanAgentSocket extends TextWebSocketHandler {
@Value("${human.agents.available}")
private int availableHumanAgents;

}

Please add that to  your code. However that still doesn't fully answer the question. Even with an @Component ifyou are doing  new HumanAgentSocket() it will achieve nothing. Also if the variable wasn't resolvable the application simply will not start, it would fail with an error.

I added this to my code but it was starting the application at run time the data from application.properties file is not coming.

Please read my comment. If the values aren't resolved the instance isn't spring managed so you are creating new instances yourself.

I was annotated the HumanAgentSocket with @Component annotation that means spring will manage this instance right? Correct If my concept is wrong.

It will manage an instance however as stated if the @Value isn't resolved you are still creating new instances of this class yourself. If there is a new HumanAgentSocket() in your code the @Component is pretty much useless.

yes Configuration
EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addHandler(new HumanAgentSocket(), "/human-agent").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
} here we I hit "/human-agent" endpoint I think it is creating new instance every-time

Please don't add code as comments that is totally unreadable. But that instance isn't spring managed (as mentioned about 3 times before). Inject the one created from @Component into your configuration and register that, don't create a new instance yourself.

Okay sir thanks.
